# Apply analysis to copyfield

Tags: solr, solr4

I wish to have a field copied, and in the copy apply one additional analyzer to it. While I know how to make the copy (`<copyField source="source" dest="dest"`) what I really want to do is run a different analyzer on the copy (ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory).

How can I change the type of the copyField so that I can run that additional analyzer?
Do I even need to change the type, or can I just run an additional analyzer?

I belive that I can sort of hack this together by using a dynamic field that will match the copy field name, and then change the type that way, but won't that create an extra copy of my data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to define a new fieldType and declare your copyField to be of that type.

For example, below `text_syn` is a type which applies a set of analyzers and `text_stop_syn_stem` is another type, which has more analyzers (for stop word removal and stemming):

```
<types>
    ...
    <fieldType name="text_syn" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>        
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>        
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>

    <fieldType name="text_stop_syn_stem" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
        <analyzer type="index">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="1" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="1" splitOnCaseChange="1"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
            <tokenizer class="solr.WhitespaceTokenizerFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory" preserveOriginal="1" generateWordParts="1" generateNumberParts="1" catenateWords="0" catenateNumbers="0" catenateAll="0" splitOnCaseChange="0"/>
            <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" words="stopwords.txt" ignoreCase="true"/>
            <filter class="solr.PorterStemFilterFactory"/>        
            <filter class="solr.RemoveDuplicatesTokenFilterFactory"/>
            <filter class="solr.ASCIIFoldingFilterFactory"/>
        </analyzer>
    </fieldType>
    ...
</types>
```

Under fields we got:

```
<field name="name_syn" type="text_syn" indexed="true" stored="true" />
<field name="name_stop_syn_stem" type="text_stop_syn_stem" indexed="true" stored="false" />
```

and the copyField is like:

```
<copyField source="name_syn" dest="name_stop_syn_stem" />
```